# Realm, android-sdk-manager not found

Tags: java, realm

I am using Realm and I wanted to import one of the example.  I got an error message "Plugin 'android-sdk-manager' not found".  I tried the solution on the other post but it didn't work for me..

How can I get the plugins?

```
apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-command'




android {
compileSdkVersion rootProject.sdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.buildTools

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'io.realm.examples.json'
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.sdkVersion
    minSdkVersion 15
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-
          android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}

command {
    events 2000
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the plugin to your dependencies? See https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin for hints.

Comment: I did download the zip....How do you install the file?  Sorry..I am new to android studio.

Comment: Typically you don't have to download zip files. Android Studio and Gradle will automatically download and install plugins as needed. After changes to your `build.gradle` files, sync. Android Studio which among other things installs the plugings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all copy the class path dependency to build.gradle file(Project):-

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.3"
}
```

}

Finally, copy and paste the following code on top of  build.gradle(App) :-

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Note:- The version 0.88.3 is subjected to change on future releases.For more please check 
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/